# Finding the Closed Form of a Multivariable Exponential Summation

Tags: summation, contest-math, generating-functions, closed-form, exponential-sum

Here was a problem I thought of after seeing the 2017 HMMT #5:

For all positive integers $n$, what is the closed form of the summation of $\sum_{a+b+c+d=n}(3^a)(9^b)(27^c)(81^d)$, where $a, b, c,$ and $d$ are non-negative integers.

Here was the original 2017 HMMT #5.

https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2017/feb/algnt/problems.pdf

In that problem they just solved using casework, but I am unable to do that here. I tried breaking up the summations but was confused on how to do so. I think that generating functions may be the key to solving this problem but I don't know how to use them. How would I find the closed form of the summation I though of?

Comment: note that the summation is given by $$\sum_{a+b+c+d=n}3^{a+2b+3c+4d}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true you can solve this problem using generating function.

Let $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3,\alpha_4) = (3,9,27,81)$, the sum at hand can be rewritten as

$$\Lambda_n \stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{\sum_{k=1}^4 e_k = n}\prod_{k=1}^4 \alpha_k^{e_k}$$
Multiply both sides by $z^n$ and sum over $n$ from $0$ to $\infty$, the corresponding OGF (oridinary generating function) equals to

$$\begin{align}
\Lambda(z) \stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Lambda_n z^n
&= \sum_{e_1=0}^\infty\sum_{e_2=0}^\infty\sum_{e_3=0}^\infty\sum_{e_4=0}^\infty 
\left(\prod_{k=1}^4 \alpha_k^{e_k}\right) z^{e_1+e_2+e_3+e_4}\\
&= \sum_{e_1=0}^\infty\sum_{e_2=0}^\infty\sum_{e_3=0}^\infty\sum_{e_4=0}^\infty 
\prod_{k=1}^4 (\alpha_k z)^{e_k}\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^4\sum_{e_k=0}^\infty (\alpha_k z)^{e_k}
= \prod_{k=1}^4 \frac{1}{1 - \alpha_k z}\end{align}
$$
Since the roots of $z$ in denominator of last expression ($\alpha_1^{-1},\alpha_2^{-1},\alpha_3^{-1}, \alpha_4^{-1}$) are distinct and simple, one can read off its partial fraction decomposition directly. The result is

$$\Lambda(z) = \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac{1}{1-\alpha_k z}
\prod_{\ell=1,\ne k}^4 \frac{1}{1 - \alpha_\ell\alpha_k^{-1}}
= \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac{\alpha_k^3}{1-\alpha_k z}\prod_{\ell=1,\ne k}^4 \frac{1}{\alpha_k - \alpha_\ell}
$$
Expanding both sides and compare coefficients of $z^n$, one get

$$\begin{align}
\Lambda_n &= \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac{\alpha_k^{n+3}}{\prod\limits_{\ell=1,\ne k}^n (\alpha_k - \alpha_\ell)}\\
&=\phantom{+} \frac{3^{n+3}}{(3-9)(3-27)(3-81)}
+ \frac{9^{n+3}}{(9-3)(9-27)(9-81)}\\
&\phantom{=} + \frac{27^{n+3}}{(27-3)(27-9)(27-81)}
+ \frac{81^{n+3}}{(81-3)(81-9)(81-27)}\\
&= \frac{-27\cdot 3^{n+3} + 39\cdot 9^{n+3} - 13\cdot 27^{n+3} + 81^{n+3}}{303264}
\end{align}
$$

As a doubt check, I have computed the first few $\Lambda_n$ by brute force

$$\Lambda_{1\ldots 6} = 120,10890,914760,74987451,6098153040,4946037697808153040$$

and above formula does produce the correct numbers.

**Update**

A web search indicate OEIS has recorded this sequence before ([OEIS A226804](https://oeis.org/A226804)). It also has a much simpler expression for $\Lambda_n$.

$$\Lambda_n = \frac{3^n(3^{n+1}-1)(3^{n+2}-1)(3^{n+3}-1)}{416}$$

**Update 2**

Playing around with an CAS, it seems above result can be generalized.

Instead of a 4-fold sum over $e_1,\ldots, e_4$ with $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_4) = (3, 3^2, 3^3, 3^4)$, we can consider a $p$-fold sum with  $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_p) = (\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots,\alpha^p)$.
As far as I can test, we have
$$
\sum_{\sum\limits_{k=1}^p e_k = n}\prod_{k=1}^p \alpha_k^{e_k}
=
\sum_{\sum\limits_{k=1}^p e_k = n}\alpha^{\sum\limits_{k=1}^p ke_k}
= \alpha^n\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{\alpha^{n+k}-1}{\alpha^k-1}
$$
This is a beautiful result <strike>but I am unable to derive it from first principle</strike>.
See Calvin Lin's answer for a derivation.

Comment: To clarify your last line, it's just a simplification of your fraction. E.g. $303264/416 = 3^6$.

Comment: @CalvinLin the simplification in denominator isn't that surprising. What intrigue me is the factorization in the numerator and why they vanish at $n = -1, -2, -3$.

Comment: I think the OEIS gets the simpler expression from $(3,9,27,81)=(3^1,3^2,3^3,3^4)$

Comment: @clathratus it is true that this is the source of surprise but I'm wondering whether this is a coincidence or there are something deeper...

Comment: I think there must be many generalizations. For example $$S_n^{(p)}(u)=\sum_{\sum_{k=1}^p e_k=n}u^{\sum_{j=1}^p je_j}$$ is given by $$S_n^{(p)}(u)=\sum_{k=1}^{p}u^{nk}\prod_{\ell =1,\ell\ne k}^{p}\frac{1}{1-\alpha^{k-\ell}}$$

Comment: For a sufficient finite set $A\subset \Bbb R$ with $f(x)=\prod_{a\in A}(1-ax)$, we have $$\frac1{f(x)}=\sum_{a\in A}\frac{a/f'(1/a)}{ax-1}, $$ as it can be shown that $f'(1/u)=-u\prod_{r\in A, r\ne u}(1-r/u)$ for any $u\in A$.

Comment: @clathratus I know that, this is essentially what I say "read off its partial fraction decomposition directly". What I am wondering is for different $p$ (the number of summation indices), do we have similar simple factorization (in the numerator).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an analogous formula for $S_n^{(3)}(3)$ unfortunately. The simplest I could manage is $$S_n^{(3)}(3)=\frac{3^n(3^n(3^n-6)-27)}{16}$$

Comment: The furthest general simplification I can manage is $$S_n^{(p)}(u)=\sum_{k=1}^{p}\beta_k^{(p)}(u)u^{(n-1)k},$$ with $$\beta_k^{(p)}(u)=-\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(uz;u)_p\bigg{|}_{z=u^{-k}}\right)^{-1}$$

Comment: @clathratus I get $S_n^{(p)}(a) = \frac{a^n(a^{n+1}-1)(a^{n+2}-1)\cdots(a^{n+p-1} - 1)}{P_p(a)}$ where $P_p(a)$ is some polynomial in $a$ for $p$ as far as I can test.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the general case where $a_i$ are distinct positive integers, and we want to find

$$ f(n, k, a) =  \sum \prod_{\sum_{i=1}^k d_i = n} (a^i) ^ {d_i}.  $$

- $ f( n, 1, a ) = a^n$, since there's only that one term.
- $ f(n, 2, a) $ can be split into terms which have $a^2$ involved, and terms which do not, giving us $f(n, 2, a) = a^2 f(n-1, 2, a ) + f(n,1,a)$. With an initial starting value of $f(0, 2, a ) = 1$, we can verify that $ f(n,2,a) = \frac{ a^n (a^{n+1} - 1) } { a- 1} $ by inducting on $n$.
- Likewise, $f(n, 3,a) $ can be split into terms which have $a^3$ involved, and terms which do not, giving us $f(n,3,a) = a^3 f(n-1, 3, a) + f(n,2,a)$. With an initial value of $f(0,3,a) = 1$, we can verify that $f(n,3,a) = \frac{ a^n (a^{n+1} - 1 ) ( a^ {n+2 } - 1 ) } { (a-1)(a^2 - 1 ) }$.
- More generally, via double induction, using the base case of $f(0,k,a) = 1$ and the recurrence

$$f(n,k,a) = a^k f ( n-1, k, a ) + f(n, k-1, a ), $$

we can show that

$$ f(n, k, a ) = \frac{ a^n \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} ( a^{n+i } - 1 )}{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} a^i - 1}.$$

---

Notes

- I tried to generalize to arbitrary integers, but didn't seem to get that nice of a result.
- The 2 variable case leads to the Geometric Progression $ f( n | a, b ) = a^n \frac{  1 - ( \frac{b}{a}) ^ {n+1 } } { 1 - \frac{b}{a}} $. You can see that when $ b = a^2$, we get a nice cancellation giving us the above formula.
- The 3 variable case can be conditioned in a similar manner as the above, but it's not immediately obvious that there is a nice simplification.

Comment: +1 beautiful. I just figured out how to show this a minute ago and you beat me on that. c'est la vie.

Comment: @achillehui This was the way I first approached it, but I thought OP wanted a GF solution given the phrasing and tags, so I didn't add it because yours was already good.  Because of your "unable to derive from first principle", and it seems that you didn't notice how the denominator factorized, so I added my solution.